# Converting JSON file to string in RestAssured (Java)

Tags: java, json, api, rest-assured

I'm using IntelliJ to learn RestAssured; this is completely new territory for me. I have a simple .json file in place and I want to have a API Response to assert if it's the same as the mentioned .json file.

Basically: If the output of the call equals what I have in the json file, it's all good.

I used the demo restapi.demoqa.com for quick reference. This is what I have right now:

```
@Test
public void ComparewithJSONinResources()
{

    String CityResponse = ?????

    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://restapi.demoqa.com/utilities/weather/city";
    RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
    Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET, "/Hyderabad");
    String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
    System.out.println(responseBody);

    Assert.assertTrue(responseBody.equals(CityResponse));

    response.body();
}
```

I have the .json file in place called CityResponse.json. For easy reference, say on the location c:/CityResponse.

Is it possible to convert the Json file to a string to assert that the API and the JSON are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing JSON as String will never give accurate results, as you will possibly see inconsistency in space, tabs (indentation), property (key-value pair) sequencing etc. Your best bet is to parse JSON into POJO using one of the many popular libraries (Ex. Jackson, GSON etc). And this deserialization you need for both `RestAssured` Http response & one you are reading from `.json` file, and once you have two java objects, use standard Java comparision by overriding `equals` method.